# Will SEO work on semi-one-page website?

Tags: seo

I am setting up a cafe. I read a lot about SEO not working well with one page websites. As such I am thinking of creating an in between with the content structure listed below. Will this be effective for SEO?

- Home Page (one page) - keywords : Cat Café Singapore, Singapore Cat Café, Cat Café,
- About Us (one page)
- Meet the Cats (one page)
- Price(one page)
- Contact Us (one page)
- Menu (stand alone) – keywords : Coffee Singapore, Tea Singapore, Café Singapore
- Research (stand alone) , keywords : Cats Singapore, Cats
- Blog (stand alone) – keywords : Cat Café Singapore, Singapore Cat Café, Cat Café,
- Shop (Stand alone ) – keywords : Cat Toys, Cat Food
- Adopt a cat (stand alone) – keywords : Cat Adpotion, Singapore Cats,

Comment: What's the difference between (one page) and (stand alone)?

Comment: home page/about us/etc, would be contain in 1 page e.g www.domain.com/home. while stand-alone pages would have their own unique URLs e.g www.domain.com/menu

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is in no way a "one page website".  You are proposing a 10+ page website.  As you add blog posts, the number of pages on your site will continue to grow.  You will have URLs like:

- / (the home page)
- /about.html
- /cats.html
- ... (one URL and page for each item you propose)
- /blog/
- /blog/2013/03/03/why-we-love-cats-so-much
- /blog/2013/04/04/a-purr-goes-well-with-coffee
- ... (one URL and page for each blog post)

A one page site is usually powered by JavaScript and AJAX.  It might have all the same content as a multi-page site but because that content is loaded with scripts, Googlebot will have a hard time crawling it.  Just avoid using JavaScript for page navigation.  Your site looks absolutely fine from a "number of pages" standpoint.

---

Some other advice about your website:

- Your proposed keywords are too broad.  Nobody who searches for "cat food" is going to want to find your website.   You should target "cat food singapore" and "cafe with cat food" which are much more specific.  Your main keyword will be your "brand" (the name of your cafe).  Make sure you include that on every page and especially target the front page to it.
- As the site for a restaurant, your two most important pages will be the menu and the "contact us" information.  The contact information is so important that you likely want to put your phone number and address on every page of the site.  The phone number is especially important if you allow people to call for take out.  The address is important so that people can find you.  The contact page can have additional information like a fax number, a map, and driving directions.
- You will want to look into "local SEO" (search on Google for that, there are lots of good articles) so that your business can be found in yellow pages sites and map sites (such as Google maps).  The biggest part of this is submitting your business listing with the correct name and categories to as many of these sites as possible.  You need the name and category so that you show up for the correct searches.  You need lots of sites to have your name, address, and phone number because the number of mentions of these items that there are on the web determines how well you show up on the map compared to your competitors.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you hope to achieve. It sounds like you have a local business - so the best advice is to follow local SEO guidelines (try here first (http://www.localvisibilitysystem.com/), set up your Google+ local business page, connect it to your website and, open a Yelp account and so on (and give great service to get great reviews)

This is a big subject and this should just get your started. The amount of pages on your site should not matter at all in this scenario.